# how to use GCM in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I propose a new question:
I think the communication between android and server by sockets is difficult

I speak with my friends it proposes me a solution: use the GCM

month then give an idea or example uses this concept

I found this book: 
http://www.academia.edu/2200380/SENDING_SECURE_DATA_BETWEEN_AN_ANDROID_MOBILE_APPLICATION_AND_A_NETWORK_GROUND_STATION

And the question is, how to use gcm between server and Android?

Comment: Whats your question.?

Comment: how to use gcm between server , android

Comment: When you read the GCM documentation (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), what did you learn?

Answer (score 0):

Communication between android and server is I believe not applicable with GCM, GCM is intended to be a server to client pushing service, for example your wish to tell your client there is some data updates you need to fetch. So your server will push a message to client, using GCM.

For client to server communication, the easiest IMO would be using some Http server or web services. As for securing you can always go for SSL.